# Access "this" from Java anonymous class

Tags: java, this, anonymous-class

Given the following code:

```
public interface Selectable {
  public void select();
}

public class Container implements Selectable {
  public void select() {
  ...
  }
  public void createAnonymousClass() {
    Selectable s = new Selectable() {
      public void select() {
        //see comment below.
      }
    };
  }
}
```

I want to access `Container.select()` from within my anonymous class' `select()` method. However, `this.select()` would again call the anonymous class' `select()` method.

My suggestion would be:

Introduce a field into Container, e.g.

```
private Container self = this;
```

Now I can access `Container.select()` by calling `self.select()` from within the anonymous class.

Is this a reasonable way? Or are there any better ways?

Answer (score 286, accepted):

```
Container.this.select();
```

Comment: I didn't know even `this` keywords could be differentiated just as methods and attributes can. +1

Comment: It should be noted that you have to specify Exactly `Container` class here. Any of its ancestors won't be accepted.

Comment: save my... night, maybe ? +1

Comment: what if we try it for the same named an anonymous class and a confidential class? (Supposed not implementing an interface.)

Answer (score 44):

You can write `Container.this.select()` to distinct from the inner class !