# How to refer to the containing class of an anonymous or nested class in Java

Tags: java

The super-class can be referred to by the keyword, `super`, and the current class can be referred to via, `this`, but is there a way to refer to the class that contains the nested class/anonymous class?

Comment: possible duplicate of [keyword for the outer class from an anonymous inner class?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/56974/keyword-for-the-outer-class-from-an-anonymous-inner-class)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. Like this:

```
public class OuterClass {
    class InnerClass {
        void method() {
            // Refer to outer class instance
            doSomething( OuterClass.this );
        }

        void doSomething(OuterClass outer) {
            // ...
        }
    }
}
```

- See also: [Access `this` from Java anonymous class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1084112/access-this-from-java-anonymous-class/1084124#1084124)

Answer (score 3):

I think you're looking for [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1084112/access-this-from-java-anonymous-class/1084124#1084124).

Basically, if your outer class is called Container you use this syntax:

```
Container.this.methodNameGoesHere();
```

That will ensure that you will be calling the outer class's methodNameGoesHere() method even if there is a duplicate method in your anonymous class.