# Access overriden function in anonymous class

Tags: java, design-patterns, polymorphism, overriding, anonymous-class

I'm attempting to extend a class in order to polymorphically run its functions as privileged. I want to avoid modifying the base class, `Fooer` in the example, and I definitely want to avoid reflection. I've been working mainly with javascript and python lately so my mind keeps repeating, "Use a function pointer" but since functions are not first class objects in java that is not an option. This seems like a valid goal so I'm assuming someone know a good design pattern for this that I'm missing.

```
public class SecureFooer extends Fooer()
{
    @Override
    public Object foo()
    {
        PrivilegedAction<Object> action = new PrivilegedAction<Object>() {
            @Override
            public Object run() {
                // This isn't going to work, i'm inside PrivilegedAction
                return super.foo()
            }
        };
        return AccessController.doPrivileged(action);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The syntax is

```
return SecureFooer.super.foo();
```

This works because the `PrivilegedAction` anonymous class is an inner class of `SecureFooer` and all inner classes have access to their enclosing instance, and to that instance's super implementation.

Comment: I tried this after reading [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1084112/access-this-from-java-anonymous-class?rq=1) just after posting this question. I verified it worked and was just about to post the answer but it appears you beat me to it. Thanks!