# How to access class inside a thread

Tags: java, multithreading, oop

I am trying to do following in gui class for notifying registred observers.

```
public class GUI extends javax.swing.JFrame implements Observer {

public notImportantMethod() {

 t = new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
                       myObject.registerObserver(this);   
                 }
            }

        };
        t.start();
      }
}
```

It gives me **error: incompatible types:  cannot be converted to Observer** How can I use this? I know inside of run there is another context but how could I access it?

Comment: What actual object are you trying to register?  The thread or the instance of GUI?

Comment: I am trying to register gui

Comment: `OuterEnclosingClassname.this` i.e. `GUI.this` will give you reference  to the current object of the outer enclosing class, GUI . When you use simply  `this` it refers to the object of anonymous class extending `Thread`

Comment: Note: your question really is not about threads.  Your question is about how a method of an _anonymous inner class_ can refer to the instance of the enclosing class for which the inner class instance was created.  The fact that your inner class extends `Thread` doesn't change the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`this` now refers a Thread. You should be able to call `GUI.this`. For more info, see  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1084112/access-this-from-java-anonymous-class) .

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for quick and dirty: (this is not good practice)

```
public notImportantMethod() {

final GUI self = this;

 t = new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
                       myObject.registerObserver(self);   
                 }
            }

        };
        t.start();
      }
}
```

Otherwise I would recommend looking up a tutorial on multi-threading and/or concurrency in java, like this one: http://winterbe.com/posts/2015/04/30/java8-concurrency-tutorial-synchronized-locks-examples/

Answer (score -1):

@Ishnark has answered it correctly. You should be able to access it via `GUI.this`, that's all that you need to do.