# Sharing objects through the app using the Application class

Tags: java, android, android-activity, mobile, global

I am trying to define global objects using the application class.
I therefore define the following class.

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {

    private MyObject myObject=new MyObject();

    public MyObject getMyObject(){
        return this.myObject;
    }
}
```

Then, I use it in an activity, but I get an error (Cannot resolve method getApplication()):

```
public class AnActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_mood);

    Button buttonMusic=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button5);
    buttonMusic.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            MyApplication myApplication = ((MyApplication)this.getApplication());
            Toast.makeText(MoodActivity.this, "playing music", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

    }
}
```

I have no clue why I get this error, as it for example works when calling the getApplication() in another activity.

I'm pretty new to Android and Java, so please excuse the ingenuity of the question.

**UPDATE**

Then I do MyObject `myObject=myApplication.getMyObject();` and I don't get any compilation issue but the app dies as soon as I get in that activity.

As I understand it is not advised to use the Application class for such use, what would be a good alternative?

Comment: Check my updated answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're getting this error because you call `this.getApplication()` inside the `View.OnClickListener`. Because of this, `this` now references the listener and not the activity.

To do what you need, just create a `Context` object outside of the listener in your activity's `onCreate` method and assign `this` to it. And, inside the listener, use `context` instead of `this`. Something like this :-

```
public class AnActivity extends Activity {
    Context context;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_mood);
    context = this;
    Button buttonMusic=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button5);
    buttonMusic.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            MyApplication myApplication = ((MyApplication)context.getApplication());//Changed "the" to "context"
            Toast.makeText(MoodActivity.this, "playing music", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

    }

}
```

**Edit after question update :-**

Instead of using the application class, use `static` objects to achieve global variables. `static` objects are independent of objects and can be referenced using the class that they belong to. For example, if you define a `static` variable in your `MainActivity.class` and name it `testObject`, then it can be accessed using the following code regardless of your current activity :-

```
YourObject object = MainActivity.testObject;
```

Answer (score 1):

Unless you have a specific reason for extending the Application class in Android you probably shouldn't. For reference, look at the note in the documentation for this: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html .

If you are trying to create an object that you can use in your Android app, simply do that as you would in Java:

```
public class MyObject {
    //Your stuff here
}
```

If there is a reason that you're specifically wanting to extend the Application class then perhaps there's more that people can do to help you if you explain what you're trying to do. I just don't necessarily see a need to go through all that complexity based on your example :)

Comment: My point is to have a global object that is shared between various activities. I define my object in the main activity and then do `MyObject myObject=myApplication.getMyObject();` and I do operations on my object. But this actually kills the app, this line makes the app bug.

Answer (score 1):

Change `this` to `AnActivity.this`.
Inside the code below the meaning of `this` changes from `AnActivity` to `View.onClickListener` as it is another object and inside those braces you are in the scope of the click listener class

```
new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            MyApplication myApplication = ((MyApplication)this.getApplication());
            Toast.makeText(MoodActivity.this, "playing music", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
```

So the code above should become

```
new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            MyApplication myApplication = ((MyApplication)AnActivity.this.getApplication());
            Toast.makeText(MoodActivity.this, "playing music", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
```

You can read a bit more about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1084112/access-this-from-java-anonymous-class)