# getLastLocation().addOnSuccessListener not work in the button

Tags: java, android, google-maps, android-fusedlocation

I want to set a button, when I put the button, then get location.

```
FusedLocationProviderClient userLocationProviderClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this);
```

This can work in **onCreate**, but I want to set a button, when I put the button,
then show me user location. It can't work. There is my code, how do I fix it?

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity{

final private int userAgreePermissionCode = 1;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    //  Check permission and go "onRequestPermissionsResult"
    int currentPermission = ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION);
    if( currentPermission!=PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED ) ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, userAgreePermissionCode);



    findViewById(R.id.Locate).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //  can't work
            FusedLocationProviderClient userLocationProviderClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this);  //  Error in here!!
            userLocationProviderClient.getLastLocation().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Location>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(Location location) {
                    Log.i("Longitude:", location.getLongitude()+"");
                    Log.i("Latitude:", location.getLatitude()+"");
                }
            });
        }
    });
}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case userAgreePermissionCode:
            if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                // Permission Granted
                Log.i("Status:","Granted");
            } else {
                // Permission Denied
                finish();
            }
            break;
        default:
            super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    }

}
```

}

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Access "this" from Java anonymous class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1084112/access-this-from-java-anonymous-class)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does not work because `this` in that scope refers to an instance of `View.OnClientListener`.

You can fix it by putting `MainActivity.this` instead, or you can just have  `FusedLocationProviderClient` as member field, instantiate it in `onCreate`, then use it within your click listener.

Answer (score 0):

only change this thing..

```
 FusedLocationProviderClient userLocationProviderClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(Location.this);  //  hear give your activity name
```