# How to choose the correct way to get relevant context in Java?

Tags: java, android, android-intent, anonymous-class

I recently started using java and I'm trying to understand what exactly "Context" is, and how to use it properly.

```java
public AdapterView.OnItemClickListener selectDevice = new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {

            String info = ((TextView) view).getText().toString();
            String adress = info.substring(info.length()-17);
            Intent comIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Communication.class); //WHY???


        }
    };
```

For this example and Intent arguement , why don't we use "getContext()" or "getApplicationContext" or just "this"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm trying to understand what exactly "Context" is

[What is 'Context' on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3572463/what-is-context-on-android)

> why don't we use "getContext()" or "getApplicationContext" or just
>   "this"?

Because `this` does not refer to the Activity in anonymous classes.
See here 
[Access "this" from Java anonymous class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1084112/access-this-from-java-anonymous-class)

Answer (score 1):

Calling `getContext()` or `getApplicationContext()`  is same as `this.getContext()` right? `this` gives an object class where you are in. So when you are able to call `getContext()` that means you are inside a class which extends Context class and has `getContext()` function.
 For example from `Activity` you can call `getContext()` because it has the function.
But in this case you are in `OnItemClickListener` class. And that class has no function `getContext()`. You have to be in a class which has `getContext()` function.